# Calculate cellular data usage per application

Tags: ios, objective-c

How to get data consumption of individual iOS application (i.e. if a device has 10 applications which consumes data, I want to know how much data each application consumes)

Comment: iOS already tells you that in the settings page.

Comment: I need to develop an application like Onavo count. So I need these datas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer: you can't.

Long answer: all iOS applications are executed in a [sandboxed](https://developer.apple.com/app-sandboxing/) environment, limiting the access that you have to data from another applications to avoid malicious behavior. The only way that you could obtain this information is if iOS had a public API that provided that information (it doesn't) or if the other applications published their information somewhere reachable from your application.